# Can someone fluent in Javascript explain to me whats going on here SIMPLY

Tags: javascript, function, iife

Im taking a course on udemy and I came across this code that changes the background of a window.  The thing is the function randColor loses me.  Id like to know exactly whats going on.

I know a function called randColor is declared, then the function itself RETURNS a function + # but I am trying to understand the logic of how it all happens.  There is a HASH symbol that is added and I believe its also an IIFE correct?

I very much appreciate the help!

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.background = randColor();
})


function randColor(){
  return '#' + (function co(lor){   return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); })('');
}
```

Comment: Whoa, what horrible code. It's a recursive IIFE instead of a simple loop, with an obfuscated one-liner body instead of two statements, with a weirdly placed base case condition.

Comment: @Bergi What is "horrible" about the code?

Comment: @guest271314 The fact that you need to explain it. It does a trivial thing in a hard-to-understand way.

Comment: @guest271314 - Would you agree that the same can be achieved by straight forward  coding without any loss of efficiency?

Comment: @PM77-1 I would say it can be achieved in a straight-forward way and *gain* efficiency

Comment: @Bergi Where is "efficiency"  within text of original Question?

Comment: @guest271314: Speed and storage.

Comment: I once wrote this type of code (in a different language) and it was later used during interviews: "What does it do and why you should not write your code in this fashion?"..

Comment: Would this be considered _efficient_? `'#'+(Math.round(Math.random()*'0xffffff')).toString(16);`

Comment: @PM77-1 The present inquiry is not a job interview, nor are benchmarks included at OP which display the different approaches tried as to a prospective estimation of "efficiency". Many do whatever their employer tells them to do. Perhaps post the same inquiry that was included in the "interviews" and same code at OP as a Question? The present Question does not present the inquiry as having any relevance to "efficiency".

Comment: @blex No, that doesn't work. You need `.padStart(6, "0")` (and also you shouldn't multiply by a string)

Comment: @PM77-1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516234/what-is-the-most-efficient-approach-to-compose-a-string-of-length-n-where-random

Comment: @Bergi _"I would say it can be achieved in a straight-forward way and gain efficiency"_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516234/what-is-the-most-efficient-approach-to-compose-a-string-of-length-n-where-random

Answer (score 4):

The goal is to generate a random color in the Hex format. My attempt to explain the code you provided us with:

When `randColor` is called it is added to the call stack and then gets paused waiting for the nested function's calls to complete.

That nested function `co(lor)` is IIFE and it is called recursively.
Initially an empty string is passed in and the local `lor` variable is assigned to it.

`Math.floor(Math.random()*16)` - generates numbers from 0 to 15 which are 
the indexes of the array `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f']`. At each step a new symbol from the array is added to the local `lor` string passed in as a parameter earlier. Updated string is passed further into a new call if its length is fewer than 6.

The nested function's recursion adds to the call stack objects with `lor` values like this (for example):

```
5aTh46 (top, last call, gets popped out first)
5aTh4
5aTh
5aT
5a
5      (first call)
```

when the length of the local `lor` variable gets equal to 6 after the 6th call, then base condition `lor.length == 6` is fulfilled and `5aTh46` string is returned from the top of the call stack. So, for the 5th call we have

`return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f']     [Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
    && (lor.length == 6) ? lor /* = 5aTh4*/ : co(lor) /* = 5aTh46*/;`

`lor.length == 6` is false since local `lor` is equal to `5aTh4`. So, `5aTh46` returned by the 6th call is returned after the 5th call as well and so forth untill value `5aTh46` is finally returned as a result of `co(lor)`'s calls and added to the `#` string inside `randColor`. In the end we get `#5aTh46`.

PS. That's how I understand it. If you get the concepts of [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) this explanation may sound simple :)

Comment: Thanks for your help I do appreciate it - im just lost because the part after return is what throws me off - why after return is there an OPENING parantheses?  I never knew that was valid javascript.  Also why are the arrays not separated by commas?

return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor);

^ so thats saying lor = lor+ the letters/numbers MULTIPLIED by a whole number between 1 and 16 AND if the length of lor == 6, then what?

Comment: Briefly, 1) after return is there an OPENING parantheses - it is a part of IIFE which in this case looks like `(function(){})()`. It is also ok like this `function(){}()` if the whole thing is a part of an expression.
2) why are the arrays not separated by commas? - there is only 1 array of symbols. The other pair of `[]` contains calculated index. it is like `['a', 'b'][1]` (= 'b') but that index `1` is calculated on the fly.

Comment: 3) return (lor += [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Mat‌​h.random()*16)]) && (lor.length == 6) ? lor : co(lor); - this is the use of conditional operator `[cond to evaluate] ? [if true] : [if false]`. The whole thing says: add one more symbol to `lor` AND if `lor`'s length is 6 return `lor`. Otherwise keep calling `co(lor)` (untill its length reaches 6 symbols).

Comment: so, things to master: IIFE, arrays, conditional operator and recursion.

Comment: Ok I think Im getting it so I did some testing in codepen - basically this whole part is a ternary operator which is the better version of an if/else statement----

 return (lor += [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d', 'e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16) ]) && (lor.length == 6) ? lor :co(lor);---

Its saying - IF lor = lor + random string AND the length is === 6, THEN lor ELSE co(lor) 

right?

Comment: Yes, it is also called ternary operator since it involves 3 operands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is an `IIFE`. The invocation starts with a `''`. Then recursive calls are made which appends 1 character at a time from the array `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f']` randomly. Six such characters are added( checked by `(lor.length == 6)`). The preceeding '#' is prepended to the 6 character to form a random color which is returned by the function `randColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function co(lor /* passed empty string */){ /* concatenate result of `co("")` */  return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
       // if `lor` string `.length` is `6` return `lor` string 
       // else call `co` with `lor` as parameter
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); })('' /* empty string */)
```

Comment: "*call `co` with `lor` as parameter*" - well yes that's obviously what the syntax `co(lor)` means. But what does it do, and why?

Comment: @Bergi _"`concatenate result of \`co("")\``"_

Comment: Well no, `co(lor)` does not "*concatenate result of `co("")`*"

Comment: @Bergi `co(lor)` returns either `co(lor)` or `lor` depending on `.length` of `lor`, the initial call is `co("")`, where `lor` is `""`

Comment: @Bergi The final result of `co(lor)` is concatenated to `"#"`

Answer (score 0):

The code at first looks terrible. Let simplify it step by step.

```
//find 1st <button> element and assign on'click' handler to it
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.background = randColor();
  //background is the **result** of execution of randColor()
})


function randColor(){
  return '#' + (function co(lor){   return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); })('');
}
```

`randColor()` returns an expression which includes a function (in fact, `IIFE`).
Let put the result instead of function call. Meanwhile, parenthesis around the function can be omitted here because of `+` operator before.

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.background = '#' + function co(lor){
   return (lor +=
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)])
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  lor : co(lor); }(''/*send empty string to lor parameter*/);
})
```

Still not easy? Let's take next step.

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.body.style.background = '#' + co(''/*send empty string to lor parameter*/);
})

function co(lor){
   return (lor += /*assignment returns the new value. always truey in this case*/
    [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f'][Math.floor(Math.random()*16)/*magic 16 is the array length*/])
    && (lor.length == 6) ?  /*returns when we have 6 character string*/lor : /*call the function recursively*/co(lor); 
}
```

And final simplification. Use a loop instead of recursion.

```
function co(){
   var lor = '';
   var hexDigits = '0123456789abcdef'.split('');
   for(var i = 0; i < 6/*required length*/;i++){
     lor += hexDigits[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)/*0 - 15*/];
   }
   return lor;
}
```

Leading `#` makes up correct `HEX` value for the color.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to propose a more simplified iterative code instead of the recursion.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
        // body
        document.body.style.background=randcolor();
    })

    function randcolor(){

        var list=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','a','b','c','d','e','f'];
        var r='#';
        while(r.length<7)
        {
            r+=list[Math.floor(Math.random()*16)];
        }
        return r;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

"#" is a part of color code (#7b7b6e), the function returns a random string something like this "7b7b6e" and # is added infront of it

Comment: We know what it's doing. The OP is asking *how* this code achieves that.