# How to filter an array of objects for case insensitive matches from any object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filtering

I have this sample code here, and I am trying to filter matching objects without exploding the code complexity or performance:

This code here filters matches based on one explicitly defined key and it's not case insensitive.

```js
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship'
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const found = people.filter((person) => {
  if (person.firstName === searchString) return true
})

console.log(found)
```

**THE GOAL:**

1. I want it to match case-insensitive
2. I want it to return matches from any key
3. I want it to find using `contains` not exact match

Something like this:

```
// const people = [
//   { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
//   { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
//   { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
//   { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
//   { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
//   { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
//   { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship'
//     rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
// ]

// const searchString = 'bob'

// ... magic

// console.log(found)

// { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
// { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
// { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
// { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship'
//   rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
```

I have scoured the documentations related to `Array.filter()` and I can definitely make solutions that involve `Array.reduce()` and looping over stuff with `Object.keys(obj).forEach()`, but I want to know if there is a concise, performant way to handle this kind of fuzzy search.

Something like this:

```
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship' },
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const found = people.filter((person) => {
  if (person.toString().indexOf(searchString).toLowerCase !== -1) return true
})

console.log(found)
```

> **[edit]** This definitely works, but is it acceptable?

```js
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship',
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const found = people.filter((person) => {
  const savageMatch = JSON.stringify(person)
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1

  console.log(savageMatch)
  if (savageMatch) return true
})

console.log(found)
```

Memory footprint optimized:

```
const found = people.filter((person) => JSON.stringify(person)
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1
)
```

Converted to a function:

```
const fuzzyMatch = (collection, searchTerm) =>
  collection.filter((obj) => JSON.stringify(obj)
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
)

console.log(fuzzyMatch(people, 'bob'))
```

There are some great answers in here; so far, I have selected this for my filtering needs:

```js
const people = [
  { imageURL: 'http://www.alice.com/goat.jpeg', firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  {
    firstName: 'Ronald', lastName: 'McDonlad', status: 'relationship',
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon'
  },
  {
    imageURL: 'http://www.bob.com/cats.jpeg', firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship',
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob hates salmon'
  },
]

const searchString = 'bob'

const options = {
  caseSensitive: false,
  excludedKeys: ['imageURL', 'firstName'],
}

const customFind = (collection, term, opts) => {
  const filterBy = () => {
    const searchTerms = (!opts.caseSensitive) ? new RegExp(term, 'i') : new RegExp(term)
    return (obj) => {
      for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
        if (searchTerms.test(obj[key]) &&
          !opts.excludedKeys.includes(key)) return true
      }
      return false
    }
  }
  return collection.filter(filterBy(term))
}

const found = customFind(people, searchString, options)

console.log(found)
```

I made it able to support case sensitivity and to exclude specific keys.

Comment: Is expected result the entire matched object or only the specific property, value pair?

Comment: Match the entire object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we assume that all properties are strings, then you might do in the following way

```
const people = [
  // ...
]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const filterBy = (term) => {
  const termLowerCase = term.toLowerCase()
  return (person) =>
    Object.keys(person)
      .some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(termLowerCase) !== -1)
}

const found = people.filter(filterBy(searchString))

console.log(found)
```

Update: alternative solution with RegExp and more old-school :) but 2x faster

```
const people = [
  // ...
]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const escapeRegExp = (str) => // or better use 'escape-string-regexp' package
  str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")


const filterBy = (term) => {
  const re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(term), 'i')
  return person => {
    for (let prop in person) {
      if (!person.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (re.test(person[prop])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;        
  }
}

const found = people.filter(filterBy(searchString))
```

Comment: This is definitely better than stringifying it, pretty sure.

Comment: I just realized I should add excluded keys also, so it can be general purpose. Yours looks like it should support that fairly quickly.

Comment: I like your usage of `.some()`. I didn't know that existed. I will mark this answer as correct after `Array.some(more time has passed)` assuming no one else comes through with mad data gems.

Comment: Updated your tests with the last solution: https://jsperf.com/fuzzy-match-objects-2

Comment: If you remove escaping, it should be a bit faster than @guest271314 solution. Actually his solution should have the escaping too.

Comment: Also checking for own properties can be not necessary in your case, so this micro-optimization should also increase performance a bit. :)

Comment: Your updated answer is quite beautiful. I encountered some trouble trying to add `excludedKeys` to guest271314's answer. I wouldn't call yours more old school. `for in` and `for of` loops support async/await. Yours is actually looking like it will be simple to add more optional config settings. I think I can finish it soon now with your updates. I will post a final answer when I'm done. Guest's answer is great but it is very rigid. It is very poetic though. Yours is supplying extra hooks with the `for in`.

Comment: I replaced your for in with `for (const key of Object.keys(obj))` ;)

Comment: @DmitryDruganov is there any way to do the same if my array of objects contains includes numbers also ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to filter the array, then filter each key in the objects to match a regular expression. This example breaks down the problem into single responsibility funcitons and connects them with functional concepts eg.

Performance tests are included, in chrome this is consistently faster than Dmitry's example. I have not tested any other browsers. This may be because of optimisations that chrome takes to allow the jit to process the script faster when the code is expressed as small single responsibility functions that only take one type of data as an input and one type of data as an output.

Due to the tests this takes around 4 seconds to load.

```js
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship', rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
]

// run a predicate function over each key of an object
// const hasValue = f => o => 
//  Object.keys(o).some(x => f(o[x]))
const hasValue = f => o => {
  let key
  for (key in o) {
    if (f(o[key])) return true
  }
  return false
}

// convert string to regular expression
const toReg = str => 
  new RegExp(str.replace(/\//g, '//'), 'gi')

// test a string with a regular expression
const match = reg => x => 
  reg.test(x)

// filter an array by a predicate
// const filter = f => a => a.filter(a)
const filter = f => a => {
  const ret = []
  let ii = 0
  let ll = a.length
  for (;ii < ll; ii++) {
    if (f(a[ii])) ret.push(a[ii])
  }
  return ret
}

// **magic**
const filterArrByValue = value => {
  // create a regular expression based on your search value
  // cache it for all filter iterations
  const reg = toReg(value)
  // filter your array of people
  return filter(
    // only return the results that match the regex
    hasValue(match(reg))
  )
}

// create a function to filter by the value 'bob'
const filterBob = filterArrByValue('Bob')

// ########################## UNIT TESTS ########################## //

console.assert('hasValue finds a matching value', !!hasValue(x => x === 'one')({ one: 'one' }))
console.assert('toReg is a regular expression', toReg('reg') instanceof RegExp)
console.assert('match finds a regular expression in a string', !!match(/test/)('this is a test'))
console.assert('filter filters an array', filter(x => x === true)([true, false]).length === 1)

// ##########################   RESULTS   ########################## //

console.log(
  // run your function passing in your people array
  'find bob',
  filterBob(people)
)

console.log(
  // or you could call both of them at the same time
  'find salmon',
  filterArrByValue('salmon')(people)
)

// ########################## BENCHMARKS ########################## //

// dmitry's first function
const filterBy = (term) => {
  const termLowerCase = term.toLowerCase()
  return (person) =>
    Object.keys(person)
      .some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(termLowerCase) !== -1)
}

// dmitry's updated function
const escapeRegExp = (str) => // or better use 'escape-string-regexp' package
  str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&")


const filterBy2 = (term) => {
  const re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(term), 'i')
  return person => {
    for (let prop in person) {
      if (!person.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        continue;
      }
      if (re.test(person[prop])) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;        
  }
}

// test stringify - incredibly slow
const fuzzyMatch = (collection, searchTerm) =>
  collection.filter((obj) => JSON.stringify(obj)
    .toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1
)

new Benchmark({ iterations: 1000000 })
  // test my function - fastest
  .add('synthet1c', function() {
    filterBob(people)
  })
  .add('dmitry', function() {
    people.filter(filterBy('Bob'))
  })
  .add('dmitry2', function() {
    people.filter(filterBy2('Bob'))
  })
  .add('guest', function() {
    fuzzyMatch(people, 'Bob')
  })
  .run()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.css">
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is actually really great. Thanks. I'll have to look at this closer tomorrow. I'm curious how this is performance-wise compared to Guest's and Dmitry's updated solutions. I was too lazy tonight to to try to make a giant array.

Comment: Run the code snippet to see the performance difference between the examples

Answer (score 2):

You should give fusejs a shot. http://fusejs.io/
It has some interesting settings such as threshold, which allow some typo error (0.0 = perfect, 1.0 = match anything) and `keys` to specify any keys you want to search in.

```
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship'
    rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' },
]

const fuseOptions = {
  caseSensitive: false,
  shouldSort: true,
  threshold: 0.2,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 1,
  keys: [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "rogueBonusKey",
  ]
};


const search = (txt) => {
  const fuse = new Fuse(people, fuseOptions);
  const result = fuse.search(txt);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with `i` modifier to perform case-insensitive matching and the method [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

- It is very convenient when you want to evaluate multiple object properties like:

  ```js
  new RegExp(searchString, 'i').test( 
    person.email || person.firstName || person.lastName
  )
  ```

Code:

```js
const people = [{ firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' }, { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' }, { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' }, { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' }, { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' }, { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' }, { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship', rogueBonusKey: 'bob likes salmon' }]

const searchString = 'Bob'

const found = people.filter(({ firstName }) => 
  new RegExp(searchString, 'i').test(firstName))

console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the entire matched object is expected result you can use `for..of` loop, `Object.values()`, `Array.prototype.find()`

```
consy searchString = "Bob";
const re = new RegExp(searchString, "i");
let res = [];
for (const props of Object.values(people))
  Object.values(props).find(prop => re.test(prop)) && res.push(props);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is cool. Unfortunately, it takes 2-3x longer to execute for some reason than Dmitry's solution.

Comment: @agm1984 Can you create a jsperf to demonstrate?

Comment: A better test would be with an array of thousands of objects. In my browser, the first one is 2-3x faster using `performance.now()`

Comment: @agm1984 At which browser did you try code? At Chromium 61 `for..of` is fastest _"Array.some
const filterBy = (term) => {
  const termLowerCase = term.toLowerCase()
  return (person) =>
    Object.keys(person)
      .some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(termLowerCase) !== -1)
}
const found = people.filter(filterBy(searchString))
115,822
±3.10%
6% slower
For of loop + Regex
const re = new RegExp(searchString, "i")
let res = []
for (const props of Object.values(people))
  Object.values(props).find(prop => re.test(prop)) && res.push(props)
122,775
±3.10%
fastest"_

Comment: Testing in Chrome 61.0.3163 / Windows 10 0.0.0

Comment: At Firefox 57 "Array.some" was faster at first run, slower at second run at *nix _" Array.some const filterBy = (term) => {
  const termLowerCase = term.toLowerCase() return (person) =>
    Object.keys(person)
      .some(prop => person[prop].toLowerCase().indexOf(termLowerCase) !== -1)
}
const found = people.filter(filterBy(searchString))
 99,771
±4.53%
5% slower
For of loop + Regex
 

const re = new RegExp(searchString, "i")
let res = []
for (const props of Object.values(people))
  Object.values(props).find(prop => re.test(prop)) && res.push(props)
 101,249
±0.82%
fastest"_

Comment: I am seeing about the same on my machine. It seems to deviate between both +/- 20%

Comment: @agm1984 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516234/what-is-the-most-efficient-approach-to-compose-a-string-of-length-n-where-random#comment80198567_46623314

Comment: Thank you. For loops are generally always faster, in my experience. I'm working with your code currently. It is quite easy to make it case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
const people = [
  { firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Smith', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'bobby', lastName: 'Suxatcapitalizing', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Jim', lastName: 'Johnson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Sally', lastName: 'Fields', status: 'relationship' },
  { firstName: 'Robert', lastName: 'Bobler', status: 'single' },
  { firstName: 'Johnny', lastName: 'Johannson', status: 'complicated' },
  { firstName: 'Whaley', lastName: 'McWhalerson', status: 'relationship',
    'rogueBonusKey': 'bob likes salmon' },
]

const searchString = 'Bob';

const person = people.find(({ firstName }) => firstName.toLowerCase() === searchString.toLowerCase());

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.filter() also works as well:

```
const includesQuery = (value) => {
      return value['SOME_KEY'].toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    }
const filtered = this.myArray.filter(includesQuery);

console.log(filtered);
```